# spellcheck in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, spellchecker

I'm wondering how to turn on the 'live' spellchecking for Sharepoint 2013 for a wiki page. I looked at the source code, and saw this: `<body onhashchange="if (typeof(_spBodyOnHashChange) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnHashChange();" spellcheck="false" class=" ms-backgroundImage">`. I then manually changed `spellcheck` to `true`, and spellcheck started working. I looked in site options, the master page and page layout, and I didn't see any options for spellcheck. How do I set that option to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution that works for us.

- Make sure everyone has saved and closed all of their work
- On the SharePoint Foundation 2010 server, browse to this folder:

> "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS"

- Look for these two files: "SP.UI.Rte.js" and "SP.UI.Rte.debug.js"
- Just to be safe, make a backup of both files.
- Open each file in the text editor of your choice.
- Search for "spellcheck", there is only one instance of the word in both files
  You should find this statement

> document.body.setAttribute("spellcheck",false)

- Change false to true
- Save and close both files
- Reset IIS by running 'iisreset' from a command prompt with Administrative rights.

Those are the steps I took and IE's built in spell check was restored for our Wiki pages.  You may not need to edit both .js files.  You may not need to iisreset.  Your mileage may vary.  Objects in mirror are closer than they appear.

Comment: I just noticed you are running 2013.  I can only guess this will work for you, but you'll need to look in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS" for the .js files.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to modify any file on the server. This can be accomplished with one line of JavaScript:

```
document.body.setAttribute("spellcheck",true);
```

If this is in a Script Editor or in th MasterPage it would have the same effect.